# Android Autolink to launch WebView

Tags: android, url, browser, webview, textview

I'm using autoLink="web" attribute in TextView to launch Browser.
However, I want to launch the myActivity with WebView, when I click the links in TextView.
Is is possible that catch the click event and invoke startActivity?

Thanks in advance,
Jason

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is fairly easy to do :)

- Create an activity with the WebView in it and the appropriate settings.
- In the TextView, allow the links to fire an intent instead.
- Make that intent one that opens the activity with the WebView in it
- In that intent object, do `myIntent.putExtra()` and add the URL as an extra
- In the WebView-containing activity, use savedInstanceState.getExtras() to retrieve the URL and load it in the WebView

You can get more information about intents and how to use them here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html

You can also [have a look here for the Notepad Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html) application that contains some very basic examples of intents working.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, T3Roar.
but I cann't understand your second instruction "allow the link to fire an intent instead".
Do you mean I don't need to do something for the textview?
How can I make my own intent for the link in the textview to lanuch specific activity?

Comment: Have a look at this article. His example called "ShowDialog" when links were pressed, but you can launch an intent there instead for your program. http://blog.elsdoerfer.name/2009/10/29/clickable-urls-in-android-textviews/

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about `autolink` set up in TextViews to automatically handle URLs in TextViews. However, the default behavior is to open the web page in an external browser, so how do we make it start an activity instead (for example)?

Under the hood, autolink is handled for TextView by [LinkMovementMethod](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/text/method/LinkMovementMethod.java), and is difficult to customise the behavior. There is now [BetterLinkMovementMethod](https://github.com/saket/Better-Link-Movement-Method), described in more detail in [this blog post](https://medium.com/@Saketme/a-better-way-to-handle-links-in-textview-27bb70b2d31c). With just a few lines of code changes, the TextView `autolinks` can be made to start an activity or all kinds of other behaviors that can be customized as desired.